# How to separate content with .each() - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two hidden `<div>` elements which are hidden at the bottom of my page like so:

```
<div class="hidden-unit" style="display:none;">
    <h1>ad unit one</h1>
</div>
<div class="hidden-unit" style="display:none;">
    <h1>ad unit two</h1>
</div>
```

Further up my page I have another two div elements, like so...

```
<div class="visible-unit"></div>
<div class="visible-unit"></div>
```

I would like to loop through each of the hidden units, place the content from the first `.hidden-unit` into the first `.visible-unit` and then likewise for the second.

The content that sits within each `.hidden-unit` will actually be an inline script used for displaying ads, this is passed through from an array into a view that I have created in PHP so there is a strong possibility that more content could be added to the array or removed, so this loop needs to accommodate for such situations.

I have tried a number of solutions using jQuery's `.each()` but I can't seem to get it right. I've also created a JSFiddle should anyone want to demonstrate a solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/p89sq2df/3/

I've tried loads of different combinations and the latest attempt only seems to be populating the `.visible-unit` elements with the 'ad unit two' text.

```
$('.hidden-unit').each(function() {
    $('.visible-unit').html($(this).html());
});
```

Anyone had to do anything like this before? I appreciate it's an odd one.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `$('.visible-unit').html($(this).html());` with `$('.visible-unit').append($(this).html());`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the index:

```
$('.hidden-unit').each(function(index) {
    $('.visible-unit').eq(index).html($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: Cheers! This seems to do the trick - I appreciate everyone's feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the index the elements so you update matching instances. This can be done using `each` or `html(function)`

```
$('.visible-unit').html(function(index){
   return $('.hidden-unit').eq(index).html();
});
```

Since you mention that the content is loaded by script originally, you may need to allow time for any asynchronous loading (if any) in the scripts

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/p89sq2df/6/)**</kbd>

Comment: Hey, this works on the jsfiddle but lpg's answer seemed to work on my actual code - I appreciate your input though, many thanks!

Comment: will both work, they essentially do the same thing, this just has less function calls in it

Answer (score 0):

```
var visibleUnits = $('.visible-unit').toArray();
var x = 0;

$('.hidden-unit').each(function() {
        visibleUnits[x].html($(this).html());
        x++;
    });
```

The gotcha is that there could be more .hidden-unit elements than .visible-unit elements, which would cause an exception.  But this you put you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to match indices and having to maintain two lists of divs, you can clone the hidden divs and add them to a container, or insert them before or after another element if you really don't want a container element.

```
$(".hidden-unit").clone()
    .removeClass("hidden-unit")
    .removeAttr("style")
    .addClass("available-unit")
    .appendTo(".container");
```

Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ygn34zL8/